# SQL server запрос для вывода ошибки

Tags: sql, sql-server

Использую DataGrip, очень нравится! Но есть один нюанс, который до сих пор не исправили, это вывод строки с ошибкой.

***DataGrip***

> [2020-07-18 09:13:12] [22018][245] Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'F' to data type int.

***Microsoft SQL Server Management***

> Сообщение 245, уровень 16, состояние 1, **строка 2**
> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'F' to data type int.

**Это очень не удобно.**

Есть ли способ вывести сообщение об ошибки в таком виде `(Сообщение 245, уровень 16, состояние 1, **строка 2** Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'F' to data type int.)` через запрос.

После выполнения запроса, который выдал ошибку.

Comment: Вам нужен номер строки, где произошла ошибка? Это никак не относится к sql или SqlServer. Этот номер выводит SSMS и не выводит DataGrip. Гугление показывает, что разрабам датагрипа такой issue давно ставится. Ждите, пока они расшевелятся.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Думаю что всё таки запросом можно это как то вытащить,  информация про ошибки думаю должна куда то писаться, Вот только куда!

Comment: Гм, ну можно попробовать [ERROR_LINE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/error-line-transact-sql). Но это в блоке try-catch.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Так я уже пробовал! Но то, и везде приходиться Try Catch писать. Думал может что то похожее на SYS.ALL_ERRORS у Oracle но не знаю точно как там это работает.

Comment: Я сильно подозреваю, что и SSMS, и DataGrip оборачивают все запросы в try-catch и в случае ошибки извлекают информацию. Но датагрип выводит не всю.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Тоже возможно!